# Determine an element in $Gal(\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)/\mathbb{Q})$

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory

Suppose $\alpha=e^{\frac{2\pi i}{221}}$, explain why $Gal(\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)/\mathbb{Q})$ contain an element $\sigma$ with $\sigma(\alpha)=\alpha^{11}$ but no element $\gamma$ for which $\gamma(\alpha)=\alpha^{13}$

I know that 221 is the product of 13 and 17, but I don't know what else I can do?
Can someone give me some hint? Thank you!

Comment: well, $\sigma(\alpha)^{221}=1$ and $\sigma(\alpha)^j$ is not 1 for $1\leq j \leq 220$, so $\sigma(\alpha)$ is a primitive 221-st root of unity.

Comment: Have you identified the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$? Do you know what other roots it has? I suspect that a few facts about cyclotomic polynomials and cyclotomic fields have been covered. Otherwise the exercise is a bit naughty.

Answer (score 4):

Since $11$ and $221$ are coprime, $\alpha^{11}$ is a primitive $221$st root of unity, so there is an automorphism $\sigma$ of $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ such that $\sigma(\alpha)=\alpha^{11}$ (since the cyclotomic polynomial $\Phi_{221}(x)$ is the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over $\mathbb{Q}$).

On the other hand, $\alpha^{13}$ is not a primitive $221$st root of unity because $13$ divides $221$. The image of $\alpha$ under any automorphism $\sigma$ of $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ must be a primitive $221$st root of unity, so there cannot be any $\sigma$ such that $\sigma(\alpha)=\alpha^{13}$.

Comment: Not sure why you mention the cyclotomic and minimal polynomial. Here the OP probably doesn't know that $\sigma$ is an automorphism of $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n)$ iff $(\zeta_n) = \zeta_n^k$, $gcd(n,k)=1$

Comment: Well the fact that the cyclotomic polynomial is irreducible is commonly how one proves that the map $\mathrm{Gal}(\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n)/\mathbb{Q})\to (\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^{\times}$ is an isomorphism rather than just being injective.

Comment: No forget it, we need to mention the cyclotomic polynomial is irreducible, at least for $n$ prime